# ERROR: syntax error at or near "DISTINCT"

Tags: postgresql

Why do I get this error? I need to select both these as distinct, but Im I coding it wrong here?

```
ERROR: syntax error at or near "DISTINCT"

SELECT DISTINCT(mfin_score), DISTINCT(empirica_score ) from account_details
```

Comment: `DISTINCT` is ***NOT*** a function.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do:

```
select distinct mfin_score, empirica_score
  from account_details
```

Keyword `distinct` is not a function. It's a keyword to state that you want only `distinct` tuples on your result set.

Answer (score 4):

`DISTINCT` is a `KEYWORD` not a `FUNCTION` hence it will be better if you try

```
SELECT DISTINCT mfin_score, empirica_score from account_details
```

Answer (score 2):

just use this

SELECT DISTINCT mfin_score, empirica_score  from account_details

Answer (score 2):

If you want the distinct couples of mfin and empirica:

```
select distinct mfin_score, empirica_score
  from account_details
```

If you want the distinct mfin and the distinct empirica you have to do something different:

```
select distinct 'MFIN' As code, mfin_score
 from account_details
union all
select distinct 'EMP' As code, empirica_score
from account_details
```

you may have to check the syntax of postgresql for Alias, not sure if it's the same as oracle

Comment: you should use `union all` here, not `union` (the constants used mean no row from the upper query can match to the lower query anyway)

Answer (score 2):

The right syntax for DISTINCT keyword is

`SELECT DISTINCT column_name,column_name
FROM table_name;`

So you can write

`SELECT DISTINCT mfin_score, empirica_score from account_details`

instead of

`SELECT DISTINCT(mfin_score), DISTINCT(empirica_score ) from account_details`

Answer (score 2):

For others like me who got this error - `DISTINCT` needs to come right after the `SELECT` (before any columns). And will deduplicate the combination of all columns supplied.

Comment: It's not "applied to the first column". It's applied to **all** column.

Comment: When I run `select distinct id, text`, it deduplicates based on id and supports duplicates of `text`. So only the `id` is distinct, right?

Comment: No, the combination of **all** columns in the SELECT list is distinct

Comment: Got it! Thank you, just updated my answer (and now I get how it works better :)). If only one value is changing across the columns, it behaves as though it's enforcing that only that variable column is distinct.